# i have return redirect page but page not reload

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade

i have return redirect page send use with function but not reload page and not show message

my blade file button click:

```
onclick="edit_offer({{$offer->id}},'{{$base_url}}')"
```

controller :

```
return redirect('offer/delete')->with('message','This Service Is Unavailable');
```

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: base_url + '/' + url + '/delete/' + id,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.success == true) {
            setTimeout(() => {
            }, 1000);
            Swal.fire({
                type: 'success',
                title: 'Deleted!',
                text: 'Record has deleted successfully.',
                showConfirmButton: false,
            })
        } else if (result.success == false) {
            alert(result.data);
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        Swal.fire({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Oops...',
            text: 'This record is connect with another data!'
        })
    }
```

Comment: Is this Laravel 5 or Laravel 8... it can't really be both.
there appears to be very little Laravel code here at all (mostly JS) and no Eloquent at all... are you sure you have given it the correct tags?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Ajax call then In controller return redirect does not work, You need to give

```
return response()->json(["success"=>"Your message"]);
```

And If you want to refresh the page on success call in javascript then you need to add the following line.

```
location.reload();
```